# How to demonstrate SQL injection in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, code-injection

I want to demonstrate the insecurity of some webservices that we have. These send unsanitized user input to an Oracle database Select statements.

SQL injection on SELECT statements is possible (through the WHERE clause), however I am having a hard time to demonstrate it as the same parameter gets placed in other queries as well during the same webservice call. 
E.g:

```
' or client_id = 999'--
```

will exploit the first query but as the same WS request calls runs other SQL SELECTs, it will return an oracle error on the next query because the client_id is referred to by an alias in the second table.

I am looking to find something more convincing rather than just having an ORA error returned such as managing to drop a table in the process. However I do not think this is possible from a Select statement.

Any ideas how I can cause some data to change, or maybe get sensitive data to be included   as part of an ORA error?

Comment: For one, *don't run these on your actual services to test!*  There are plenty of examples out out there demonstrating SQLi.  Use those.  But for the love of God, *don't try to just inject random code into your production services to see them break!*

Comment: Secondly, I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for.  If you want some string that you can inject into your service that will give you sensitive data, then no one here can help you with that.  From how the question reads, it sounds like you're intentionally attempting to either get sensitive data or *drop entire tables* via SQLi in a production web service at your company.  If that's really what you're trying to do to illustrate to the company that it's a problem...  then I'd imagine you won't be working too much longer.

Comment: Then don't tie it to the table.  ' or 1 = 1' --  Really you need to convince them unsanitized user input is a problem?

Comment: You could run it on your prod environments @Siyual; just create an empty table `SQL_INJECTION_TEST` and try to drop that... seeing it happen from prod may be more effective than from a put-together demonstration.

Comment: It depends on the SQL statement that is getting dynamically produced. If you have something like `$sql="SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE bar='".$parameter."';";` Then you could set $parameter to `';DROP TABLE foo WHERE 'a'='a` and your resulting $sql would be `SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE bar='';DROP TABLE foo WHERE 'a'='a';` Which would be bad.

Comment: @Ben True, you can.  Though, it's still a bit too much on the risky side for my taste.  But you're correct, you can do it that way.

Comment: @JNevill: your example wouldn't work with Java because the JDBC driver only allows to run a single statement at each call to `execute()`

Comment: @Siyual How can an answer designed to show a risk be too risky?

Comment: @Siyual It is a test environment, not production.

Comment: @Siyual Furthermore I am not attempting to get production sensitive data nor dropping tables or getting fired. If someone were to teach you the risks of SQL injection it would just be better if you actually saw some adverse effect or something leak rather than just an ORA error. I thought I made that point clear enough.

Comment: @zyked You have some suggestions.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Blam An answer designed to show a risk can be too risky much the same as merely pointing out a crack in a structure is not as risky as noticing the crack and pushing on it to show it can be broken.  I'm horrible at analogies, but my point was that it sounded like he was doing it in a live/production environment, which has the potential of ending horribly.  But, as he stated, he's in a development environment.

Comment: @Siyual What part of demonstrate is not clear.   SQL injection as a crack is widely documented and apparently not enough.

Comment: @Blam It is clear...  and I agree it should be demonstrated... all I was saying was this line: `such as managing to drop a table in the process` did not read like he was just trying to show an error.    Though, re-reading that sentence, he does state the opposite...  I'm not trying to argue with anyone here...  only that there's a right way and a wrong way to demonstrate SQLi, and I misread and thought he was implying he was doing it in a way that could end badly.

Comment: @JNevill unfortunately it runs on Java and as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, only one statement can be run at a time.

Blam I tried various,  ' or 1 = 1', getting other client's information and from a network trace I noticed it is blocking on the different aliases. 

I just thought that there is might be an obvious way to highlight the seriousness of such a system being released. I will still make my point though. a1ex07's answer of creating a huge subquery will be mentioned as well. Thanks all for the discussion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to find and exploit a specific security weakness in a production system.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp The question asks for demonstration of tangible damage that can be done by sql injection in select statements in web services. If it makes you all happy next time I'll phrase the question as if I am programming insecure webservices myself, and ask what is wrong in unsanitized inputs if no apparent damage can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very easy to change data, but it's still possible. Function that created with `pragma autonomous_transaction` can contain dml and may be called in `where`. For instance,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_funct return int
IS
 pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
DELETE FROM test_del;
commit;
return 0;
end;

-- and then 
 SELECT null from dual where  test_funct()=1;
```

Another option you try creating huge subquery in `WHERE` which in turn may cause huge performance issue on server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a custom function, you can use a sub-query:

```
" or client_id = (SELECT 999 FROM secret_table WHERE username = 'Admin' AND password_hash = '0123456789ABCD')"
```

If the query succeeds then you know that:

- There is a table called `secret_table` that can be seen by the user executing this query (even if there is not a user interface that would typically be used to directly interact with that table);
- That it has the columns `username` and `password_hash`;
- That there is a user called `Admin`; and
- That the admin user has a password that hashes to `0123456789ABCD`.

You can repeat this and map the structure of the entire database and check for any values in the database.